# how to get all rows ng2-smart table

Tags: angular

I have a smart table component in my app where user can insert records to the table by using default features. Then user needs to click on "Save" button (not part of smart table) in order to save records into the database. How can I retrieve all records entered into the table to the onSave() function ?

Following are my html code

```
<ng2-smart-table class="dataTable" [settings]="settings" [source]="source">
</ng2-smart-table>
<br/>
<div class="row" style="float: right; padding-right: 15px;">
    <div class="container-btn" > 
    <button class="btn btn-blue-bordered btn-sm" style="margin-right: 5px;">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-blue btn-sm" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
settings = {
  actions: {
  add: true,
  edit: true,
  delete: true,
  position: 'right'
},
add: {
  addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
  createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
  cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
},
edit: {
  editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
  saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
  cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
},
delete: {
  deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
  confirmDelete: true,
},
columns: {
  property: {
  title: 'Property',
  type: 'String',
  width: '30%'
},
value: {
  title: 'Value',
  type: 'String',
  width: '60%'
 }
 }
};

tableData = [];
source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();

ngOnInit() {
   this.tableData = //load data from API
   this.source.load(this.tableData);
}

onSave() {
   //retrive all table records
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following promise `getAll()` to get all rows from `source`

```
 this.source.getAll().then(res =>{
  console.log(res); 
});
```

[doc](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)

**update**

```
//declare
source: LocalDataSource;
tableData = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.tabledata = //gettin info from API
    this.source = new LocalDataSource([]);    
    this.source.load(this.tableData.slice(0));     
  }
```

Comment: Actually I tried this. but always it returns nothing. It seems two way bindings are not supported for this.source

Comment: Nice that's a great!!